# Node command line shell + es6

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to play with `nodeJs` in the interactive shell as I do with python. But bumped with strange behavior.

[image]

How to execute such statement? Or maybe JS programmers don't use command line shell like in python world peoples do?

ps: Got it, nodejs 7.50 doesn't support es6

Comment: Why are you trying to use the spread syntax on something that is not iterable? Fwiw, the code in your first screenshot threw `TypeError: account[Symbol.iterator] is not a function` in my version of node, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written in your REPL is no valid javascript. What you wanted to do looks more like

```
let account = [{"name": "alex"}]
[...account, {"name": "jon}]
```

The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) works only with iterable, objects are not part of it

Comment: thanks, I got it. Seems as node js 7.5.0 doesn't support es6

Comment: Well I think it has a pretty decent [support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node65)